# Debian Buster booting into tty instead of graphical environment

Tags: debian, systemd, kde, startx

I need some help on this. When I boot into Debian 10 (buster) x86_64 with Plasma KDE it doesn't go into the graphical environment and I have to first login in the terminal and then run 'startx'

I looked around a bunch and still haven't solved this.

- running `systemctl status graphical.target`:

> ```
> graphical.target - Graphical Interface
>
> Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/graphical.target; indirect; vendor preset: enabled)
>
> Active: active since Thu 2020-04-09 12:11:13 WEST; 6min ago
>
> Docs: man:systemd.special(7)
>
> running 'systemctl get-default'
> systemctl get-default
>
> graphical.target
> ```

- running  `systemctl list-dependencies graphical.target`  everything seems OK
- running `systemctl status display-manager.service`

> ```
> sddm.service - Simple Desktop Display Manager
>
> Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/sddm.service; indirect; vendor preset: enabled)
>
> Active: active (running) since Thu 2020-04-09 12:11:13 WEST; 8min ago
>
> Docs: man:sddm(1)
>
> man:sddm.conf(5)
>
> Process: 389 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c [ "$(basename $(cat /etc/X11/default-display-manager 2>/dev/null))" = "sddm" ]
> (code=exited, s
>
> Main PID: 394 (sddm)
>
> Tasks: 2 (limit: 4915)
>
> Memory: 13.3M
>
> CGroup: /system.slice/sddm.service
>
> └─394 /usr/bin/sddm
> ```